Is there a name for the rhetorical device used in Acts 5:4?
In Acts 5:4 Peter says "...thou hast not lied unto men, but unto God."
Is there a name for when one says a true fact is false in order to emphasize a more important truth?
It is true Ananias lied unto men, but what was more important is that he lied to God.

It sounds a lot like hyperbole to me.

It may be some form of hyperbole.  I just wondered if there was a specific term for saying something true was false to make the point or add the emphasis in that way.

Google told me Acts 5:4 in NIV, anyway, says "...You have not lied just to human beings but to God". That's a hugely different meaning which seems to me to demand an explanation for your version…

@RobbieGoodwin In this case, the KJV (quoted by the OP) follows the Greek wording closely: οὐκ ἐψεύσω ἀνθρώποις ἀλλὰ τῷ θεῷ. The NIV translators probably thought the wording was confusing (since, as pointed out, it is not true if taken over-literally), so they added the word "just" to clarify it.

Thanks DLosc and then what? Are you saying NIV guys were right, or KJV was fine and NIV interfered without need?

The KJV is the proper rendering.  You can see similar renderings in the ESV, NKJV, NASB, LSB, and more.
